# What causes the LoginActivity to run for the first time in the Socket.io android application example by nkzawa?

Tags: java, android, socket.io

I have been trying to fully understand nkzawa's android example on github for socket.io

Relative link: 
https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/nkzawa/socketio/androidchat
(AndoridManifest.xml is in the "main" folder)

I have been told that android decides which activity to run first from a  tag inside AndroidManifest.xml that would have < action ... .MAIN and < category ... .LAUNCHER inside the activity. When I look at AndroidManifest.xml I see the aforementioned tags inside of the MainActivity declaration. Great! So MainActivity must be the first to run. Now, when I look at MainActivity.java I see an onCreate() method that just sets the content view with not much else to be seen.... So how does the LoginActivity start?

I have setup the server side of things without an issue and I can compile and run the example, connect to my server and all that... I just don't understand how the onCreate() method is first called for the LoginActivity.

There is definitely something I am missing. The LoginActivity must be started somewhere else besides AndroidMainifest.xml or MainActivity.java..

If anyone could point me in the right direction even it would be great! Thanks so much.

Comment: Since the only thing  `MainActivity` really does is load its layout, you should have a look at the [layout XML](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml), and see what it contains.

Comment: Thank you mike! This little hint really helps me follow the code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I got it.

1. App starts at MainActivity.onCreate()

2. Sets content view with: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

3. Activity_main.xml opens a fragment that uses class MainFragment

4. MainFragment.onCreate() does some work then calls startSignIn()

5. startSignIn() calls startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_LOGIN)  with the intent as the LoginActivity!

Now the LoginActivity has begun :)